# Unable to start virtual domain in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am unable to start a virtual machine on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

libvirtd version 4.0.0
qemu/kvm version 2.11.1

I am trying to start a VM on two numa nodes, I have allocated 1G hugepages and I have edited the libvirtxml indicating multiple numa nodes.

I have a total of 320 GB of Memory and have allocated 160 GB to each numa node (0 and 1).

When I tried to start the VM , usign virsh start  I get the following error:

$ virsh start vpre
error: Failed to start domain vpre
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu_madvise: Invalid argument
madvise doesn't support MADV_DONTDUMP, but dump_guest_core=off specified
2020-10-27T05:21:19.537730Z qemu-system-x86_64: -object memory-backend-file,id=ram-node0,prealloc=yes,mem-path=/dev/hugepages/libvirt/qemu/3-vpre,size=163840000000,host-nodes=0,policy=bind: cannot bind memory to host NUMA nodes: Invalid argument

Comment: That sounds very much like https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1499492 or https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1515933 which both ended up being configuration issues. Could you revisit your guest config in that regard and start a bit lower, say 100G each. If that works then ramp it up slowly  to ensure there is no unexpected off-by-one happening.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianEhrhardt for your help. that was the issue I had to exactly allocate the same amount of memory per NUMA node. Memory total allocated 335544140, each numa node needed 167772074.